# Connection between vector triple-product and $SU(3)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, vectors

Here $SU(3)$ is the set of all unitary matrices with ${\rm det}= 1$.

$$
\det \pmatrix{A_x & A_y & A_z \\B_x & B_y & B_z \\ C_x & C_y & C_z}=1,
$$

whereas the triple product $C \cdot (A \times B)$ is

$$
\det \pmatrix{A_x & A_y & A_z \\B_x & B_y & B_z \\ C_x & C_y & C_z}=V.
$$

Can we then connect $SU(3)$ to some set of $V$-preserving transformations?

Comment: The (absolute value of the) determinant gives the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $A,B,C\in\Bbb R^3$. If you take three vectors in $\Bbb C^3$, what volume are you going to talk about?

Comment: @Ted Just the value V produced by the triple-product. It is not required that V be a volume.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, yes, the product rule for determinants tells you that if $T\in SU(3)$, then the determinant you get with $TA, TB, TC$ is the same as the determinant you get with $A,B,C$. (Make the vectors into column vectors instead.)

Comment: @Ted I am actually coming from the other way around. In an equation, I have the triple product as an invariant, and I am hoping to find any additional restrictions (if any) such that the triple product is isomorphic to SU(3)?

Comment: Without saying you have a unitary transformation, you will just have $SL(3,\Bbb C)$.